# Connect SQL Server through SQL Studio but not able to connect through JDBC program

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I was writing JDBC program to connect SQL Server 2000 version using JDBC driver 7.0.0 version. but it always return error as

> The TCP/IP connection to the host **.***.**.***, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

But I was able to connect through  SQL Server Management studio. What could be the issue? I am using SQL server Authentication to connect.

1. Is that JDBC driver 7 is compatible with SQL Server 2000 version DB & Java 8?

Thank you

Comment: 2000?? That's years and years old. Please post connection string of both JDBC and SSMS

Comment: Yes it is very old and here is the code String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://**.***.**.***:1433;DatabaseName=dbname;";
            String user = "user";
            String pass = "password";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

Comment: Did you read the System Requirements section of the [JDBC Driver 7.0 page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57175)? It requires at least SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. However, configuring think client (like dll file and all), I am able to connect. I am suspecting some network issue.